# Compare diff of multiple texts and concatenate to create a super set in Python

Tags: python

I have the following three sentences.

1. Supply and install the material for renovation services. (Size 100 cm X 200 cm)
2. Supply and install the material for renovation services. (500 sq.m)
3. Renovation services - Supply and install the material.

I need the following output.

> Supply and install the material for renovation services. (Size 100 cm X 200 cm) (500 sq.m) Renovation services -

I can achieve this using the `split()` function and then performing word-by-word comparisons.

Is there any other way (maybe using `regex`) or any library that can help me with this task?

Comment: You should generalize the problem a bit more. If you always have these brackets to split on, then split should do the job.

Comment: It can be any content (and not necessarily brackets) but what I need is a text which is a superset. Instead of comparing word-by-word, I need something which helps me to select the phrase which is common in all three texts. `Supply and install the material` in the above case.

Comment: It is worth looking at the the well-known `longest common substring` problem. See for example [link](https://pypi.org/project/pylcs/)